# How to display the products in the wishlist of particular customer?

Tags: product, magento2.2, customer, wishlist

I want to `display` the `products` which are contained in the `wishlist` of a `particular customer`. Pls can anyone help me in this.

Comment: Are you using "Magento Enterprise Edition"?

Comment: No.. community edition

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
private $wishlist;

    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $wishlist
    ) {
        $this->wishlist = $wishlist;
        ...
    }

    ...
    $customer_id = 1;
    $wishlist_collection = $this->wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customer_id, true)->getItemCollection();

    foreach ($wishlist_collection as $item) {
        print_r($item->getProduct()->getName());
    }
```

Reference [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224689/how-to-get-the-wishlist-collection-of-a-customer-by-customer-id-in-magento2)