# How to get the wishlist collection of a customer by Customer Id in magento2

Tags: magento2, customer, products, wishlist

I am trying to get the wishlist products collection of a particular customer by the customer Id. but it is not working. I am using the following code :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$wishlist = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist');
$wishlist_collection = $wishlist->loadByCustomerId($userId, true)->getItemCollection();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
private $wishlist;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $wishlist
) {
    $this->wishlist = $wishlist;
    ...
}

...
$customer_id = 1;
$wishlist_collection = $this->wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customer_id, true)->getItemCollection();

foreach ($wishlist_collection as $item) {
    print_r($item->getProduct()->getName());
}
```

Comment: Why wishlist does not update immediately when i add/remove product from/to wishlist? I can see it updated on magento wishlist page but not on the page where i have written this code. It refresh data after i refresh page 4-5 times. I am working on local.

Comment: @Dinesh Yadav, I want to collect wishlist data for all customers as a CSV. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a block class as shown below :

```
class Wishlist extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
 {

/**
 * @var CollectionFactory
 */
protected $_wishlistCollectionFactory;

public function __construct( 
    -------------,

    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory $_wishlistCollectionFactory
)
{
   $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory = $_wishlistCollectionFactory;

}

public function getWishlistForCustomer($customerId)
{
  return $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory->create()
                ->addCustomerIdFilter($customerId);
}

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer to display product names from wishlist? I use code  foreach ($wishlist_collection as $item) {
    print_r($item->getProduct()->getName());
}  but i can not get data.

Comment: I solved my issue by using code from this link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250483/how-get-wishlist-in-magento-2-rest-api

Comment: You can simply get the data of wishlist from `$this->_wishlistCollectionFactory->create();` function and add the output data in a csv using fputcsv() function of php

Comment: @Dinesh Yadav, Can you please share me the sample code on getting wishlist collection as a CSV file?