# Get Product Item From Wishlist Share

Tags: magento2, wishlist, share-wishlist

I am using magento2.3.5-2

I have overwrite wishlist share module as below

`<preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Send" type="Shop\Custom\Controller\Wishlist\Share" />`

now the content execute function for the file `app/code/Wowshop/Custom/Controller/Wishlist/Share.php` is as below

```
public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $captchaForName = 'share_wishlist_form';
        /** @var CaptchaModel $captchaModel */
        $captchaModel = $this->captchaHelper->getCaptcha($captchaForName);

        if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        $isCorrectCaptcha = $this->validateCaptcha($captchaModel, $captchaForName);

        $this->logCaptchaAttempt($captchaModel);

        if (!$isCorrectCaptcha) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Incorrect CAPTCHA'));
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/share');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        $wishlist = $this->wishlistProvider->getWishlist();
        if (!$wishlist) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Page not found.'));
        }

        $sharingLimit = $this->_wishlistConfig->getSharingEmailLimit();
        $textLimit = $this->_wishlistConfig->getSharingTextLimit();
        $emailsLeft = $sharingLimit - $wishlist->getShared();

        $emails = $this->getRequest()->getPost('emails');
        $emails = empty($emails) ? $emails : explode(',', $emails);

        $error = false;
        $message = (string)$this->getRequest()->getPost('message');
        if (strlen($message) > $textLimit) {
            $error = __('Message length must not exceed %1 symbols', $textLimit);
        } else {
            $message = nl2br($this->escaper->escapeHtml($message));
            if (empty($emails)) {
                $error = __('Please enter an email address.');
            } else {
                if (count($emails) > $emailsLeft) {
                    $error = __('This wish list can be shared %1 more times.', $emailsLeft);
                } else {
                    foreach ($emails as $index => $email) {
                        $email = trim($email);
                        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($email, \Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress::class)) {
                            $error = __('Please enter a valid email address.');
                            break;
                        }
                        $emails[$index] = $email;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if ($error) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($error);
            $this->wishlistSession->setSharingForm($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/share');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout $resultLayout */
        $resultLayout = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_LAYOUT);
        $this->addLayoutHandles($resultLayout);
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

        $sent = 0;

        try {
            $customer = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerDataObject();
            $customerName = $this->_customerHelperView->getCustomerName($customer);

            $message .= $this->getRssLink($wishlist->getId(), $resultLayout);
            $emails = array_unique($emails);
            $sharingCode = $wishlist->getSharingCode();

            try {
                foreach ($emails as $email) {
                    $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(
                        $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                            'wishlist/email/email_template',
                            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                        )
                    )->setTemplateOptions(
                        [
                            'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                            'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId(),
                        ]
                    )->setTemplateVars(
                        [
                            'customer' => $customer,
                            'customerName' => $customerName,
                            'salable' => $wishlist->isSalable() ? 'yes' : '',
                            'items' => $this->getWishlistItems($resultLayout),
                            'viewOnSiteLink' => $this->_url->getUrl('*/shared/index', ['code' => $sharingCode]),
                            'message' => $message,
                            'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore(),
                        ]
                    )->setFrom(
                        $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                            'wishlist/email/email_identity',
                            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                        )
                    )->addTo(
                        $email
                    )->getTransport();

                    $transport->sendMessage();

                    $sent++;
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $wishlist->setShared($wishlist->getShared() + $sent);
                $wishlist->save();
                throw $e;
            }
            $wishlist->setShared($wishlist->getShared() + $sent);
            $wishlist->save();

            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

            $this->_eventManager->dispatch('wishlist_share', ['wishlist' => $wishlist]);
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Your wish list has been shared.'));
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*', ['wishlist_id' => $wishlist->getId()]);
            return $resultRedirect;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            $this->wishlistSession->setSharingForm($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/share');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to get the list of wishlist items being shared

I am thinking of something like this

`$item = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item::class)->load($itemId);`

but I don't know how to get the `$itemId` from the wishlist id like this data for example

`$wishlist->getId()`

any help is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/224690/82670

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
protected $_wishlistCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
    ...
    Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory $wishlistCollectionFactory
    ) {
    $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory = $wishlistCollectionFactory;
    ...
    }

    
    public function getProductCollection()
    {
            
            $wishlist = $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('wishlist_id', $wishlist->getId());            

            foreach ($wishlist as $product) {
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($product->getData());
                echo "</pre>";
            }
            die();
    }
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer, I also found another way to make this work, that is by collection the wishlist data from customer session, like below

Comment: $customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId();$wishlist_collection = $this->wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customerId, true)->getItemCollection();

Comment: Glad to hear.. finally you found it.!!