# Get product data from wishlist_id in wishlist.js

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, wishlist

I am using Magento2.3.5-p2

In `vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/web/js/wishlist.js`

I want to be able to get the product data from the wishlist_id

the code is like this

```
_beforeAddToCart: function (event) {
            var elem = $(event.currentTarget),
                itemId = elem.data(this.options.dataAttribute),
                qtyName = $.validator.format(this.options.nameFormat, itemId),
                qtyValue = elem.parents().find('[name="' + qtyName + '"]').val(),
                params = elem.data('post');

            if (params) {
                params.data = $.extend({}, params.data, {
                    'qty': qtyValue
                });
                elem.data('post', params);
            }
        },
```

if I `console.log("Params", params);` I can see that I am able to get data like this

```
data:
item: "703157"
qty: "1.0000"
uenc: ""
```

thus I am thinking from the item or wishlist_id value of `703157` I might be able to get the details of the product from this wishlist id

I have tried using

`'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'`

but no value is corresponding to the wishlist_id

any help is kindly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use an ajax call to retrieve the product data?
I think the value:

**item: "703157"**

is the id of the wishlist ID, so you can send it to a controller and return a json with the values you need and work with it.

Comment: Is there documentation or reference on how do I get the product data from the wishlist_id

Comment: I am able to get the product from the wishlist_id using this $item = $this->itemFactory->create()->load($wishlistID);$product_id = $item->getProductId(); but it seems like if the data is configureable product is does not call its simple product so I am unable to get its variant detail like Color,

Comment: Well, you can get the products from the wishlist, then you can use the productRepository to retrieve the product information.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224689/how-to-get-the-wishlist-collection-of-a-customer-by-customer-id-in-magento2